# is it possible to change ssrs parameter name (prompt) dynamically at runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

Is it possible to change ssrs parameter name dynamically at runtime? I am using ssrs server side reports in my web application and want to change ssrs parameter name (prompt) dynamically at runtime from c# code. I am not sure whether it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think is not possible. You need to specify the name of parameters and cant change when the report was deployed on the server report.